# How to tell lucerne(alfalfa) apart from clover?

Tags: identification, weeds, clover

This question has zero utilitarian purpose and is purely out of curiosity.

Mature lucerne is huge compared to clover. But when it's 10 cm tall they look [very similarly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfalfa#/media/File:%DB%8C%D9%88%D9%86%D8%AC%D8%A7.jpg). How to tell what plant is there?

Answer (score 2):

Easy, Medicago species have the central leaflet on a longer petiole (stalk) than the other two.
[image]

And clover [image]